# Пишу скринсейвер для Windows. Как показать окно с настройками?

Tags: delphi, windows, delphi-7, хранитель-экрана

Есть экранная заставка(.scr) написанная на Delphi. 2 формы: 1 форма для анимации, 2 форма для настроек. По комбинации клавиш вызывается вторая форма с настройками. При нажатии на "Параметры.." в Параметрах экранной заставки, включается анимация (1 форма), а я бы хотел, чтоб появлялась вторая форма с настройками.

[image: Параметры экранной заставки]

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При нажатии на кнопку "Параметры" заставка запускается с параметром `/c`, где также в передается значение дескриптора окна (`hwnd`), поверх которого следует показывать форму параметров. Итого вид: `/c:HWND`.
Поэтому ваша задача сводится у к тому, чтобы при запуске приложения в `dpr` проверить `paramCount` и переданный параметр. 
Еще может быть параметр `/p HWND` - это превью на форме выбора заставки, здесь передается дескриптор панели предпросмотра на форме и `/s` это предпросмотр в полном экране, а `/S` это автоматический запуск.

возможно, по [этой ссылке](http://teran.karelia.pro/articles/item_4489.html) еще что-нибудь полезное найдете